# Array shifting to the next element

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I move elements in an array to the next element

```
eg: x[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }; // initial values
    x[0] = 6; // new values to be shifted
    x[5] = { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 }; // shifted array, it need to be shifted, 
                              // not just increment the values.
```

This what I've done so far. It's wrong, that's why I need help here. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int x[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

  int array_size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);

  x[0] = 6;

  int m = 1;

  for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++) {
    x[m+j] = x[j];
    cout << x[j] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start this copying in array from end index of the array rather then from starting,because when you start copying the element from start you will loose the next element. So change the for loop

Comment: Please note "off by one": x[m+j] = x[j]; will try to overwrite the element with index "array_size" which is outsize the array - that's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

  int x[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

  int array_size = sizeof (x) / sizeof (x[0]);

  for (int j = array_size - 1; j > 0; j--) {

      x[j] = x[j - 1];
  }

  x[0] = 6;

  for (int j = 0; j < array_size; j++) {

      std::cout << x[j];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this intentionally run the risk of producing a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 14):

```
#include<algorithm>

// ...
std::rotate(x, x+4, x+5);
x[0] = 6;
```

Comment: sorry. i don't want to use algo.

Answer (score 8):

To "move rightwards" you have to iterate from the end of array:

```
for(int j = array_size - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
   x[m+j] = x[j];
   cout << x[j] << endl;
}
```

otherwise you just overwrite all the elements with the 0th element.

Please note `array_size - 2` - otherwise you have "off by one" trying to access the element beyond the array end and that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @azam: I only pointed out the major problem in your code. You still have to put the value into the [0] element yourself and you'll have to iterate over the array for the second time to get the output.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should shift the old values in the array *before* you write the new value. But instead of a loop, you are better of using [`memmove()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/). Or even better with [`std::vector`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) instead of an array - it handles all these low-level issues for you, including automatically resizing the array when needed.

Comment: But I guess this is homework, so loops and index manipulation is required I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case where you need to shift `m` elements (where `0 <= m <n`): Start from the end of the array. If you start at the begining (index 0) then you overwrite and then move that overridden value.

Studying the source code of `std::memmove` may be instructive as well.

Comment: I think this solution, and the one using rotate are better than the ones using for loop. Using library routines is always better than writing your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the end of the array. You copy the

- element in 2nd last position to the
  last position,
- element in 3rd last position to the
  2nd last position,
- ....
- element in first position(index 0) to the 2nd
  position and finally
- copy the new number in the first
  position.
  .

.

```
for(j = array_size-1; j >0; j--) {
 x[j] = x[j-1];
}
x[0] = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() 
    {
       int x[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        int array_size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);

        int m = 1;

        for(int j = array_size-1; j > 0; j--) {
           x[j] = x[j-m];
           cout << x[j] << endl;
        }

       x[0] = 6;
       return 0;
    }
```