# Adding a parameter at beginning of argv[]

Tags: c++, linux

```
if( PIN_Init(argc,argv) || !KnobMaxThreads.Value() )
    {
        return Usage();
    }
```

To add another argument at the end, I could do (argc-1,argv)

```
if( PIN_Init(argc-1,argv) || !KnobMaxThreads.Value() )
{
    return Usage();
}
```

How do I add an argument at the `beginning` instead of the `end`?
I use it something like this: `argv[argc-1]`

Tried:

```
GLOBALFUN int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    extern KNOB<UINT32> KnobMaxThreads;
    PIN_InitSymbols();
    if( PIN_Init(argc-1,argv) || !KnobMaxThreads.Value() )
    {
        return Usage();
    }
    int array_size = sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0])
    cout<<"size : "<<array_size<<endl;
    for(int j=array_size -1;j>0;j++)
    {
     argv[j] = argv[j - 1];
    }
    char path[3000] = "";
    cout<<"path : "<<argv[0]<<endl;
    getchar();
    sprintf(path, "%s", argv[argc-1]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array shifting to the next element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650372/array-shifting-to-the-next-element)

Comment: You need to shift the array values one spot to the right, to make room at argv[0] to hold a new value.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3650415/103081

Comment: also, wouldn't passing `(argc-1,argv)` tell `PIN_Init()` that there is one less parameter in argv, instead of adding a parameter?

Comment: I don't think `(argc-1, argv)` would add an argument; it would remove the last argument for most purposes (it depends whether the called function uses the argument count that is passed or looks for a null pointer at the end of the list of arguments).

Comment: It would tell it to consider one less argument before calling usage.
I would instead want that argument to be the first one and from what i've tried so far is not possible via the linked question.

Comment: Higher level languages like Perl or Python or JavaScript often provide a `shift()` and `unshift()` method on arrays, but C does not.  C is going to require you to create a new array of the correct size and type for a new array that is one element bigger, set new[0] to your new element, then loop to copy element old[i] to new[i+1].  The linked answer demos the shifting part.

Comment: This is what i've tried, Paul. Please look at it.

Comment: Your loop needs to `j--` , it starts with a large j and works down.

Comment: No that's wrong, pistal

Comment: I think we collided... `j>0;j++` is infinite, except it will fault outside the array.

Comment: Also, you need a new array to copy into that is one element larger.  You can't reuse argv this way.

Comment: Why not? Why cant it be used like that?

Comment: If you want to add an element in the beginning you have to allocate an array that is 1 element bigger than the old one.  You can loop through and copy the old values to newArray[1]..newArray[n] and then fill in newArray[0].  Or you could skip the loop and just memmove the whole old array to newArray[1] in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int c, char* v[]){
  for (int j = 0; j<c; j++)
    {
      std::cout << j;
      std::cout << " " << v[j];
      std::cout << "\n"; 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char *extra = "My New 1st Param";
  char *newargs[argc+1];
  std::cout << "before \n";
  print(argc, argv);
  for(int j = 0; j<argc; j++)
    {
      newargs[j+1] = argv[j];
    }
  newargs[0] = extra;   // warns -- not too fond of this

  std::cout << "after \n";
  print(argc+1, newargs);

  return 0;
}
```

sample output

```
$ ./a.out hello
before 
0 ./a.out
1 hello
after 
0 My New 1st Param
1 ./a.out
2 hello
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of non-sense in your code, and your explanations of what you try to achieve are not very clear.

1) You wrote "To add another argument at the end, I could do (argc-1,argv)". This seems wrong, if argv contains 10 elements for example, you are saying it contains only 9. I don't see where you add anything at the end? So when you call "PIN_Init(argc-1,argv)", the PIN_Init function knows it has an array of 9 elements (even if there are in fact 10 of them). It would be able to operate on the elements from 0 to 8 only, **skipping the last one**.

2) As other said, you can't easily add an element at the front of an array. Your code is particularly wrong in many ways:

```
int array_size = sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0])
```

This is a constant and does not depend on the content of argv. Basically both sizeof return the size of a pointer (usually 4 on a 32 bits architecture, 8 on a 64 bits architecture, but it does not matter here) and thus the computation always yields 1.
If you want in array_size the number of element in the array, just use argc.

```
for(int j=array_size -1;j>0;j++)
```

This will never loop: array_size is always 1, j starts at 0, the condition is never satisfied. And it's good because if it starts iterating, it will never stop before entering undefined behavior (signed integer overflow).

Since you tagged C++, the best way is surely to use std::vector:

```
std::vector<char *> newArray(argc+1); // vector containing one element more than required
newArray[0] = "my new element at the begining";
for(int arg = 0; arg < argc; ++arg)
    newArray[arg+1] = argv[arg];
// Can safely replace the loop with:
// memcpy(&newArray[1], argv, argc*sizeof(argv[0]));
```

Pure C code requires explicit dynamic memory allocation:

```
char **newArray = (char **)malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(argv[0]);
// Exactly same as before
newArray[0] = "my new element at the begining";
for(int arg = 0; arg < argc; ++arg)
    newArray[arg+1] = argv[arg];
// Can safely replace the loop with:
// memcpy(&newArray[1], argv, argc*sizeof(argv[0]));

// Don't forget to call: free(newArray)
```

Comment: I prefer this to an example I constructed.